# Google Cloud Run - Understanding of Authenticating end users

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-run

I have a web application which runs until now with cloud run, but without access restriction. Now it should be available only for certain users.
I read https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users and also tried both
mentioned ways: Google-Sign-In and the "Identity Platform" tutorial.

If I understand correctly, you have to program the actual user handling yourself in both variants. For example, determining which email addresses have access to the application, etc.
I was looking for a declarative way where, ideally, I only maintain a list of permitted email addresses and the "cloud run application" is only "magically" linked to this. With the result that only these users get access to the web application. That doesn't seem possible?

Ideally, the actual application should not be changed at all and an upstream layer would take care of the authentication and authorization, possibly in conjunction with the "Identiy Platform".

Best regards and any hint is welcome
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @Pentium10's answer, you can also make all users authenticate to your app somewhat forcibly. (Imagine you're building an internal portal for your company, or an `/admin` panel for your app that only certain users/groups can access.)

This sort of use case can be achieved by placing [Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP)](https://cloud.google.com/iap) in front of your Cloud Run service. That way, *all* requests go through this proxy that validates the caller. This is not like Identity Platform in the sense that visitors don't create accounts on your website (they use existing Google accounts or other IdPs like ActiveDirectory, or whatever you configure on IAP).

I have a little tutorial at https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-iap-terraform-demo/ since IAP+Cloud Run integration is still not GA and therefore not fully documented.

Comment: I will have a look into this. Thank you.

Comment: It works well. However it would be good to have it extensible for multiple cloud-run-backend-services and ingress rules. Let say: I have ten backend cloud-run services and one load balancer for all with path-mapping-rules for every entry point. Otherwise I had to duplicate the pattern you mentioned for every additionally backend-service with its own loadbalancer and this would become expensive and over sized.

Comment: I extended the solution for multiple backend services an entry path configuration via lb-http-module configuration.

Answer (score 5):

Let me add some sugar to this to better understand all these.

A Cloud Run application is packaged by you, you maintain the source code, if this is a website, placing a login button and handling authentication is your job to accomplish.

A Cloud Run system which is running all this on a hardware, it doesn't "look into" or handles your application code outside of the "code". Simply put it doesn't know if it's a Java or Python code and how to handle authentication out of the box for you - but read further.

If you require a simple way to authorize look into [API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway) it can be placed "before" Cloud Run. It might not be exactly your use case. These exists only for "API" designed services.

That upstream layer you need is the managed [Identity platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/quickstart-email-password?hl=en_US), but the CODE should be assembled by you and deployed inside your Cloud Run service. The code will be the UI driven part, the authorization logic is handled by the Identity Platform so it reduces the amount of development time.

Your users would sign up using a dedicated registration page, and sign in by entering their emails and passwords. Identity Platform offers a [pre-built authentication UI](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web) you can use for these pages, or you can build your own. You might also want to support additional sign-in methods, such as social providers (like Facebook or Google), phone numbers, OIDC, or SAML.

Look into some of the advanced examples to get a feeling how authorization can be customized further: [Only allowing registration from a specific domain](http://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/blocking-functions?hl=en_US#only_allowing_registration_from_a_specific_domain) you could reuse one of these samples to maintain that shortlist of users that you mentioned.

Comment: This sounds correct. The thing that led me astray is that Cloud Run makes you think that it handles auth automatically. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/identity-platform . But, I think this document is only a fraction of what's necessary. The reality is that you need to put a gateway in front of your cloud run service.